# How to use SQL query data in an if statement in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to create some code in C# that retrieves data from an SQL database and I'm aiming to try and use the query in an `if` loop if that's possible.

Currently I have the following code:

```
private int Num;    
private string String1;

SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("SQL Connection string");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "Select * From Part Where Part.String1 like '%' + 'k' + '%'";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

sqlConnection1.Close();

if String1 like '%' + 'k' + '%'
{
    if(Num <= 50)
    {
        Num += 1;
    }else if(Num >= 50)
    {
        Num += 2;
    }else if(Num <= 100)
    {
        Num += 2;
    }else if(Num >= 101)
    {
        Num += 3;
    }
}
```

I'm aware that a normal `if-else` statement is like:

```
if(condition){
    //statement
}else{
    //statement2 
}
```

I'm also aware that the code I currently have might need some improvement and alteration.

Is there a way of using an SQL statement in the condition section of the `if` statement?

Comment: What is the actual requirement?

Comment: You want to check that if "String1" contains "'%' + 'k' + '%'"  or not right.. ?

Comment: @un-lucky the requirement is to add 1, 2, or 3 onto the total as an upper-buffer type scenario to test the durability of the product

Comment: @Bhanupratap I want to check it contains "'%' + 'k' + '%'"

Comment: Firstly, Num is never assigned a value. Secondly, to implement a 'like' condition you might want to look at regular expressions.

Comment: @user2867342 it's assigned a value earlier on in the code

Comment: ok then you can use Contains method of string class.

Comment: @user3283410 Not that I can see. Nothing happens between declaration and test.

Comment: @Bhanupratap do you think the Contains method might help?

Comment: yes, contains can help you to find case sensitive and insensitive both and you can also check for specific characters if you want to.

Comment: @user3283410 are you expecting the '%' to act like a select statement? If so, does that mean you're just checking for the 'k'. I.e. <any-text>k<any-text>? If so, Contains will work but might produce false-positives depending on your data.

Comment: @Bhanupratap Thanks for the help :)

Comment: your welcome!.. :)

Comment: @Bhanupratap quick question, would the contains method be used instead of the SQL data?

Comment: Contains() method can be used with any thing that is in string form.

Comment: @Bhanupratap thanks once again